# Network Profile - Gaming Account Bug

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-exchange

I couldn't find this listed, and I'm not quite sure if this is the right place for it, but here goes.

On the stack exchange network profile, under the accounts listing, it shows that I have answered 0 questions on the gaming site, when I have answered 1.  Potential bug?

**EDIT**
I just visited my profile again after asking this question, and it says I've asked 0 questions as well.

**EDIT**
Here is the link to my [network profile](http://stackexchange.com/users/447677?tab=accounts)  You can see that there are no answers under the gaming section.

Comment: It's probably database lag. Doesn't make sense to query the database *every time* something changes.

Comment: @Raven - I thought so too, but the answered question was from days ago.

Comment: When I visit your profile on the main site, it shows that you have answered one question. It doesn't show that you've asked any questions, however; if you have, could you link one of them (assuming you manage to find it without it being in your account info)?

Comment: @Mana - The only question I've asked related to gaming is this one.

Comment: Oh, wait, network profile. Man, I swear I'm going blind or something...Reproduced there, no answer shows up.

Comment: @drneel This meta question now shows up on your network account's activity tab. Still no sign of the answer, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer should appear now.

This question will not (at least on the top tab) since it doesn't have a score of 5 or more.  You can see both on your activity tab however.